# React function is not returning promise even when a promise is explicitly returned (Firebase Storage)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on my Firebase project and it was working fine until yesterday - it has been a month or so. I didn't know why it ***surreptitiously*** stopped working.

In a nutshell, my function called *uploadProfilePic* below is used to return a Promise from Firebase Storage.

```
// upload [profilePic] to [destPath]
export const uploadProfilePic = (destPath, profilePic, isCropped) => dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestUploadPicToStorage(destPath));

    let ref = storageRef.child(destPath);

    // create file metadata including the content type
    var metadata = {
        contentType: profilePic.fileType,
    };

    // upload the data_url string to Firebase's Storage
    if (isCropped)
        return ref.putString(profilePic.cropURL, 'data_url', metadata); // promise returned
    else
        return ref.putString(profilePic.oriURL, 'data_url', metadata); // promise returned
}
```

I added a *Promise.all()* to check if any of the promises is not resolved. It worked for the past month and stopped working yesterday. I don't have the faintest idea why it stopped working out of a sudden.

```
export const uploadOriAndCrop = (username, profilePic, isOriPicUpdated) => dispatch => {
    let croppedPath = "/users/" + username + "_cropped_profile_pic" + profilePic.fileType;
    let oriPath = "/users/" + username + "_profile_pic" + profilePic.fileType;

    const promises = [];

    // upload cropped pic to firebase storage
    const promise1 = dispatch(uploadProfilePic(croppedPath, profilePic, true));
    promises.push(promise1); // promise1 is undefined

    // if we need to update the original picture
    if (isOriPicUpdated) {
        // upload original pic to firebase storage
        const promise2 = dispatch(uploadProfilePic(oriPath, profilePic, false));
        promises.push(promise2); // promise2 is undefined
    }

    // [promise1, promise2] is "undefined"
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

The thing that befuddled me is that it works perfectly if I call it this way:

```
...
ref.putString(profilePic.cropURL, 'data_url', metadata)
.then((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot);
})
...
```

I could easily get away by repeating the third code snippet a couple of times. However, I want my codes to be clean and short.

Could anyone tell me what's the possible reason behind the "undefined" values returned by *uploadProfilePic* when it is called in *uploadOriAndCrop*?

Thanks!

**Additional Information**

`ref.putString(profilePic.cropURL, 'data_url', metadata);` does return a value and is not undefined.

```
    // upload the data_url string to Firebase's Storage
    if (isCropped)
    {
        const val = ref.putString(profilePic.cropURL, 'data_url', metadata);
        console.log(val);
        return val; // val is not undefined
    }
    else
    {
        const val = ref.putString(profilePic.oriURL, 'data_url', metadata);    
        console.log(val); // val is not undefined
        return val;
    }
```

Comment: Check the dispatch function. Does it return the result of the computation?

Comment: Hi @Drag13 ! ref.putString(profilePic.cropURL, 'data_url', metadata) does return a value and is not undefined.

Comment: I see that ```const promise2 = dispatch(uploadProfilePic(oriPath, profilePic, false));``` returns undefined. That means that or dispatch function returns nothing or uploadProfile. No other options :)

Comment: Yeah. The thing that puzzled me is that why is it not undefined when I console.log() before I returned the value in uploadProfilePic. Somehow, the return value is not returned to the caller function. I have provided an additional snippet above. @Drag13

Comment: Hard to say, but I don't understand this line:
```dispatch(uploadProfilePic(croppedPath, profilePic, true));```
As I see ```uploadProfilePic``` returns function that expects dispatch as an argument. So it should not work. Could you check this one:
```uploadProfilePic(croppedPath, profilePic, true)(dispatch)```

Comment: I think I might know the reason. I messed around with my Redux middleware a few days ago. Reverting back my custom middleware to my previous Git commit fixed the issue. I might need to find another way to customise the middleware. Thanks!

Comment: Yout welcomed, have a nice day!